# creating a dataframe from specific range in googlesheet

Tags: python, pandas, gspread

My `gsheet` has different data set in a single sheet. I want to create a data frame from a specific range of cells (`E1:K20000`). I am using the below code for that using pandas:

```
sh5= gc.open_by_url('Link of spread sheet')

wks5=pd.DataFrame(sh5.worksheet_by_title("Pincode - fos").range('E1:K7'))

wks5.head()
```

But the result comes something like this:

[image: Result]

How can I create a `dataframe` without showing cell index and with proper headers?

Comment: Try to add `.get_all_records()` after range()

Answer (score 0):

The parameter that you are passing to `pd.DataFrame` is in fact a list of Cell objects:

```
sh5.worksheet_by_title("Pincode - fos").range('E1:K7')
```

You need to instead get the value property of each cell on that list:

```
cell_list = sh5.worksheet_by_title("Pincode - fos").range('E1:K7')
value_list = cell_list.get_all_values()
wks5 = pd.DataFrame(value_list)
```

Comment: Still the error comes as list object has no attribute 'get_all_values()'